# Distribution recommendation for a multiseat setup using dual-head and supporting direct rendering

Tags: distribution-choice, multi-monitor, multiseat

I have two keyboards, mice and monitors and a ATI Radeon HD 4290 onboard a ASUS M4A89GTD PRO/USB3 mainboard. Can you recommend a distribution or livecd that supports the GPU and offers easy means to setup a dual-head multiseat system where both sessions have direct rendering enabled? (32 or 64 doesn't matter here, although 64 bit are preferred)

Comment: related [Tutorial (or livedisk) for multiseat setup with dual-head display supporting openGL direct rendering?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5429/tutorial-or-livedisk-for-multiseat-setup-with-dual-head-display-supporting-open)

Comment: I would recommend Gentoo for anything.  It's the most stable distro I've ever used.  It may not work with the newest hardware, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the hardware for test something like this, but I would recommend Gentoo if you like to compile your stuff and be a little late with the latest software.

However, I am using Sabayon right now, it is based on Gentoo (testing repo). They take it, test it, compile it and release it. So, it's a kind of Gentoo on steroids and it is much more user friendly. It should be able to handle what you need.

Comment: I was somehow hoping for a more out-of-the-box solution, but I guess if I happen to have more spare time I _will_ have a look at Gentoo. Or Sabayon, thanks for pointing that out